# mysql. I want to get the max value of all rows with a specific date and use the corresponding fields

Tags: php, mysql, date, max

My table 'players_online'

```
id | count | date      | time  | day | max-players

0  | 55    | 26/05/16  | 13:00 | 5   | 300
1  | 33    | 26/05/16  | 13:10 | 5   | 300
2  | 43    | 26/05/16  | 13:20 | 5   | 300
3  | 100   | 27/05/16  | 13:00 | 6   | 300
4  | 43    | 27/05/16  | 13:10 | 6   | 300
5  | 56    | 27/05/16  | 13:20 | 6   | 300
```

desired output (todays highest count)

```
id | count | date      | time  | day | max-players

3  | 100   | 27/05/16  | 13:00 | 6   | 300
```

Also

(yesterdays highest count)

```
id | count | date      | time  | day | max-players

0  | 55    | 26/05/16  | 13:00 | 5   | 300
```

And

(Higest total count)

```
id | count | date      | time  | day | max-players

3  | 100   | 27/05/16  | 13:00 | 6   | 300
```

My knowledge of mysql has gotten rusty and I have no idea how to get it right. previously I tried the following which didn't select the right **time**.

```
SELECT MAX(count) AS maxcount, date, time FROM players_online WHERE date='".date('d-m-y')."'
```

I'm building a little stats page where you can view the highest player count of a minecraft server today (until now), yesterday and the highest player count of all time with their corresponding date, time, day and max-players.

Hope somebody can give me a hand.

Comment: maybe change this `date('y/m/d')` look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do a simple query that orders by count and is limited to 1.

```
SELECT * FROM players_online WHERE date = '27/05/2016' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1
```

That should get you the highest count.